# How to assign ranking on objects based on a value in a queryset

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a queryset that returns a list of menus that and I want to assign each Menu a rank based on the number of votes accumulated is there a way I can achieve this using django Query Expressions? I'm also open to any other suggestions.

The queryset is as follows:

**qs = Menu.objects.filter(Q(created_at__date__iexact=todays_date)).order_by('-votes')**

And the Menu class model is shown below:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    """Represents menu class model"""
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='menus/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

After serializing the queryset returns the following data:

```
[
  {
        "id": 10,
        "file": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dw9bllelz/raw/upload/v1/media/menus/index_ah660c.jpeg",
        "restaurant": "Burger King",
        "votes": 10,
        "created_at": "2021-06-03T09:33:05.505482+03:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "file": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dw9bllelz/raw/upload/v1/media/menus/index_ah660c.jpeg",
        "restaurant": "Texas Plates",
        "votes": 2,
        "created_at": "2021-06-03T09:33:05.505482+03:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "file": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dw9bllelz/raw/upload/v1/media/menus/index_ah660c.jpeg",
        "restaurant": "Carlito Dishes",
        "votes": 2,
        "created_at": "2021-06-03T09:33:05.505482+03:00"
    },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "file": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dw9bllelz/raw/upload/v1/media/menus/index_ah660c.jpeg",
        "restaurant": "Kram Dishes",
        "votes": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-06-03T09:33:05.505482+03:00"
    },

]
```

Comment: You already have the `order_by('-votes')` then isn't the _index_ (or `index + 1` to be more accurate) of the item in the array its rank?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I get your point I can rank by index from the list and handle when items have same number of votes to have same rank.

Comment: If you want you can also use [Window functions (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) and use `Rank` or `DenseRank` ([Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#window-functions)) as per your needs.

Comment: are you using django rest framework?

Comment: @Sarath Chandran K  yes, I was using django rest framework. I resolved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the *index* of the object in the array as its index or you can use [`Window` functions [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) and use the `Rank` or `DenseRank` ([Reference [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#window-functions)) function to compute the ranks as per your need:

```
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import Rank


qs = Menu.objects.filter(
    Q(created_at__date__iexact=todays_date)
).annotate(
    rank=Window(
        expression=Rank(),
        order_by=F('votes').desc(),
    )
)


for menu in qs:
    print(menu.rank, menu.votes)
```

Comment: It's only returning the filtered queryset I can't see the ranks:  `[<Menu: Burger King 3 VOTES>, <Menu: Westeros Munchies 1 VOTES>, <Menu: Burger King 1 VOTES>, <Menu: Burger King 1 VOTES>, <Menu: Pizza King 0 VOTES>]`

Comment: @PhilipMutua why would it show the rank in the querysets string representation? That calls `__str__` of the model to generate those representations. Check my edit the model instances do get annotated with the rank.

Comment: How to keep the original rank after applying a filter to `qs` queryset?